# ngRequired error with custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `ng-required` with my custom directive with angular 1.4.7
`<my-directive ng-required='vm.dane.zaplacone!=1'></my-directive>` and I have `Error: [$compile:nonassign]` - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=vm.dane.zaplacone!%3D1&p1=ifInputLabel
But validator works as it should - what's worng - I think I didn't saw it with angular `1.4.5` but I don't see any changes in changelog concerning `ngRequired`

Comment: Are you using minified version of Angular? If so, please use non-minified version as you will get much more sensible error messages. Also note that `ngRequired` depends on `ngModel` controller, so that might be the issue.

Comment: ngModel is there - it's just shortcut. I'm using minified version

Comment: Wierd thing whe I switched to normal error disapeared